# I'm trying to get the first two characters of my string to only output on the listbox

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the first two characters of my string to only output on the listbox,

```
string vin = "1GCHC24U83E614546";
string output = string.Format("{0} {1}", 
                              (vin.Length - 16).ToString(), 
                              (vin.Length - 15).ToString());

lsBox.Items.Add(output.ToString());
```

What am I doing wrong?
it outputs a "1 2" when I want "1 G"

Answer (score 4):

Because `vin` contains 17 characters, `vin.Length` equals 17, and `vin.Length - 16` equals `1`, and `vin.Length - 15` will be `2`.

So, your code is equivalent to:

```
string output = string.Format("{0} {1}", 
                              1.ToString(), 
                              2.ToString());
```

That's why the string representations will be `"1 2"`. Not `"1 G"`. You will not get first two characters of your string on this process, you will get string representation of two integers with it.

You need to use [`String.Substring(Int32, Int32)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) like:

```
string vin = "1GCHC24U83E614546";
string output = vin.Substring(0, 2); // output will be "1G"
```

If you want to use them in a `string.Format`, simply you can do;

```
string output = string.Format("{0} {1}", 
                              vin[0], 
                              vin[1]); // output will be "1 G"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is probably less practical than Soner`s answer in your case, but may be useful to know about, e.g. if you want to play around with string.Format():

```
string vin = "1GCHC24U83E614546";
string output = string.Format("{0} {1}", 
                              vin.First(),  // Linq syntax to take first char
                              vin.Skip(1).First()); // take the second char
```